# Node -v comand is working but npm -v comand is not working

Tags: javascript, npm

'Call : c: program files/nodejs/node.exe"prefix -g' is not internal or external commond**strong text**

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to add the node in the systems environment variables
[Here's how to do it. (ADDING NODE TO THE ENV VARIABLES](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-resolve-node-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-error-after-installing-node-js/) 
Optionally you can install the nvm (node version manager) which will make your life easier managing the installation and the versions 
[Here's how to do it. (NVM INSTALLATION)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-windows)